# How could I generate vector with numbers from givig interval in J language?

Tags: j

I'm not programmer so please explain me in details.

What I want: if I have interval `[2,5]`, I need a function which will take

- ends of interval
- and number of elements needed to be generated.

For example let there be function `myfunction` and I give it the following parameter values:

```
2 5 10
```

It shall return a vector like:

```
2 2.3 2.6 2.9 3.2 3.5 3.8. 4.1. 4.4 4.7
```

Thanks

Comment: Is this for J or Java?

Comment: Is there any mathematical relation between `2`, `5` and '10'? For example, such as: `2 * 5 = 10`. Or that's only a coincidence?

Comment: it's example. It could be 100 or 1000 or 5. It only shows how many elents from range I need

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1 The library script 'numeric' has `steps`:

```
load'numeric'
steps 2 5 10
2 2.3 2.6 2.9 3.2 3.5 3.8 4.1 4.4 4.7 5
```

You can exclude the last element (11th) with `curtail }:`:

```
}: steps 2 5 10
2 2.3 2.6 2.9 3.2 3.5 3.8 4.1 4.4 4.7
```

---

2 Another way, if you don't want to use the library, is to a) take the step size, b) multiply it by the number of steps and c) add the starting point:

```
'a b steps' =: 2 5 10
]r =: (b -a) % steps         NB. step size
0.3
]l =: r * i. steps           NB. list of steps
0 0.3 0.6 0.9 1.2 1.5 1.8 2.1 2.4 2.7
a + l                        NB. steps + starting point
2 2.3 2.6 2.9 3.2 3.5 3.8 4.1 4.4 4.7
```

You can write this as a "function" (verb):

```
f =: 3 : 0
'a b steps' =. y
a + ((b-a) % steps) * i.steps
)
f 2 5 10
2 2.3 2.6 2.9 3.2 3.5 3.8 4.1 4.4 4.7
```